# How to correctly calculate the viewport height on mobile without taking the address bar into account?

Tags: html, css

On mobile devices, the viewport height calculation isn't working properly as it's taking into account the address bar of the browser. As seen below, option 4 goes below the bottom bar

Image of viewport calculation:

[image: Image of viewport calculation]

We had put a patch in for `webkit-fill: available` on the container of the multiple choice question responses, but that didn't resolve the issue and caused other layout issues on other mobile devices. The article we referred to was https://allthingssmitty.com/2020/05/11/css-fix-for-100vh-in-mobile-webkit/

Image of webkit-fill patch:

[image: Image of webkit-fill patch]

Here's the expected behavior that we're looking for:

Image of the expected behavior:

[image: Image of the expected behavior]

Any help on how to properly calculate the viewport height would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just had a look at this quickly, I know that my comment does not solve the issue with 100vh but wanted to ask if you tried to have the footer set as position fixed to the bottom of the screen instead of working with 100vh and then apply padding-bottom to the main body equal to the footer height. Maybe you can work around it in a different way for now.

Comment: Hi Omar. The footer is currently set as a fixed element at the bottom of the screen. One of the reasons that we went with the with a viewport height solution is that the parent of the multiple choice responses doesn't have a fixed height. This was one of the only ways for the multiple choice question's container to have its full height, and be placed correctly on the page.